# Парсинг JSON по протоколу Decodable на Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто парсил данные на swift4 с помощью протокола Decodable.

Никак не пойму как раскрасить такой JSON:

```
{
  "42": {
    "42": 1,
    "USD": 42655.65,
    "EUR": 34603.51
  },
  "BTC": {
    "42": 0.2304,
    "USD": 9828.49,
    "EUR": 7973.16
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если только по этому судить, то Вам нужно использовать `CodingKeys`, т.к. 42 нельзя использовать как имя переменной. Пример:

```
struct ExchangeRates: Codable {
    let mainCoin: Double
    let USD: Double
    let EUR: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mainCoin = "42"
        case USD
        case EUR
    }
}

struct Currencies: Codable {
    let mainCoin: ExchangeRates
    let BTC: ExchangeRates

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mainCoin = "42"
        case BTC
    }
}

// Проверяем
let currencies = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Currencies.self, from: jsonData)
print(currencies.BTC.mainCoin) // 0.2304
print(currencies.mainCoin.USD) // 42655.65
```