# Парсинг JSON через Codable. Swift

Tags: json, swift

Здесь уже есть похожий вопрос [Парсинг JSON по протоколу Decodable на Swift 4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795336/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-json-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83-decodable-%d0%bd%d0%b0-swift-4), но там как я понял у автора все заработало, а у меня в идентичной ситуации не хочет. Вот и вопрос, как это сделать правильно и чтоб заработало.

Вот кусочек моего JSON:

```
"67": {
        "name": "Аксессуары",
        "sortOrder": "29",
        "image": "image/catalog/im2017/4.png",
        "iconImage": "image/catalog/style/modile/acc_cat.png",
        "iconImageActive": "image/catalog/style/modile/acc_cat_active_s.png",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "311",
                "iconImage": "",
                "sortOrder": "2",
                "name": "Маски, повязки на лицо",
                "type": "Category"
```

Ссылка на весь JSON на всякий случай : http://blackstarshop.ru/index.php?route=api/v1/categories

А вот мой код:

```
struct PreCategory: Codable {
    var a: Category
    var b: Category
    var c: Category
    var d: Category
    var e: Category
    var f: Category
    var g: Category
    var h: Category
    var i: Category
    var j: Category
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a = "67"
        case b = "68"
        case c = "69"
        case d = "73"
        case e = "74"
        case f = "123"
        case g = "156"
        case h = "165"
        case i = "233"
        case j = "0"
    }
}

struct Category: Codable {
    
    var name: String
    var sortOrder: String
    var image: String
    var iconImage: String
    var iconImageActive: String
    var subcategories: [Subcategory]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case sortOrder
        case image
        case iconImage
        case iconImageActive
        case subcategories
    }
}

struct Subcategory: Codable {
    var id: String
    var iconImage: String
    var sortOrder: String
   var name: String
    var type: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case iconImage
        case sortOrder
        case name
        case type
}
}



class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://blackstarshop.ru/index.php?route=api/v1/categories") else {return}
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if let data = data,
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments){
            //print(json)
                
            }
            
            
            do {
                
                let categoryJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(PreCategory.self, from: data!)
                print(categoryJSON)
            
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

А итогом всего этого безобразия является ошибка:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "67", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "subcategories", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 10", intValue: 10), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

***Заранее спасибо всем, кто откликнулся.***

Answer (score 0):

where are few type mismatches in server response.
For example:

```
"id":"217", //String
"id":67, //Int
```

To resolve the issue, you can fix types on server-side, or you can use some special type on client side, which can parse both int and string, for example:

```
enum NumerableString: Codable {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .int(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(NumerableString.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for NumerableString"))
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .int(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
    
    func getStringValue() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .string(let x):
            return x
        case .int(let x):
            return String(x)
        }
    }
}
```

and change yur code to:

```
struct Category: Codable {
        
        var name: String
        var sortOrder: NumerableString

......

struct Subcategory: Codable {
        var id: NumerableString
        var iconImage: String
        var sortOrder: NumerableString
```

Comment: Переведите ваш ответ на Русский язык

Comment: Я так понимаю основная проблема в том, что сервер присылает вместо "29" просто 29 ? Ну то есть там где должен быть String, и в парсе из-за кавычек выглядит как String,  приходит Int ?

Comment: в некоторых местах в поле subcategories->id:"217" сервер присылает String(в кавычках), а в некоторых - subcategories->id:67 - это int (без кавычек)
декодер успешно разбирает стринги, а когда попадает на int - выкидывает ошибку